# mysql compare column and subquery

Tags: mysql, comparison, subquery

**sql query:**

```
select
usr.username,
(
  select usr2.username
  from users as usr2
) as another_user
from users as usr
having usr.username != another_user
```

how can i compare `usr.username` with a subquery for example named as `another_user`?

i want to get all results where the `usr.username` is not equal to `another_user`

i tried the `WHERE` clause or the `HAVING` but still get error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax
```

Comment: can you fill out more of your query?  what are you putting in between those parenthesis?

Comment: i simply get another user from the same table

Comment: Forget the sql for a minute... what exactly are you trying to accomplish? If you tell us that, we can help you better, because your query looks kinda strange - it's unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: This works for me: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ac6f/1 Which `MySQL` version are you using? Please post the whole query exactly as you run it, verbatim.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a result set you're hoping to get?  As this is (although this is badly formed), for every user you have you'll get a list of every user it's not.

Comment: actually it seems to work now... weird that it wasnt working before...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select
usr.username,
(
  select username from users where ...
) as another_user
from users as usr
where usr.username <> another_user.username
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    select
    usr.username,
    (
      ....
    ) as another_user
    from users as usr
) AS T
WHERE
    NOT T.username = T.another_user
```